# Setting wordpress in a VM with ubuntu

Tags: azure, ubuntu, ssh, web, virtual-machine

Some time ago a friend of mine configured me a VM Ubuntu built to allow me construct a Wordpress site through SSH... given some technical issues I had to delete the VM and Im trying to remake one, I already know how to set the wordpress through SSH but not how to configure the VM so It can LET me do it (I tried making one but it doesnt have the same folders like WWW inside /var)

Comment: Can you describe your specific goal in the new VM? It is not clear i think

Comment: to host a wordpress website

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to deploy wordpress on a LAMP stack.
There are some prerequisites:

open your terminal and
run this commands to install the server:

`sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
​sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

run this commands to install php:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mysql libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-cgi php7.0-gd
```

Then you have to create a database like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE wpdb;
```

​GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wpdb.* TO 'USERNAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ADMIN_PASSWORD';
​FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
​EXIT;

and finally get and install wordpress:

```
wget -c http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
​​tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz
sudo mv wordpress /var/www/html
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress
```

​    sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/wordpress

and rename the config file

```
cd /var/www/html/wordpress
```

​    sudo mv wp-config-sample.php wp-config.php

restart the server:
    sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
​    sudo systemctl restart mysql.service

and voila', wordpress is ready to be served

Comment: Thank you very much, but my question is the steps to follow BEFORE this, at the moment of setting the Ubuntu VM, all the specifications to follow in azure